# Typesetting the numerator and denominator in the same font as other characters in a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the display, I want the `a` and `2` in

```
\begin{equation*}
y=-\frac{a}{2}x^{2}
\end{equation*}
```

to be typeset in `font=\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,
    ymin=-5.5,ymax=10.5,
    restrict y to domain=-5.5:10.5,
    xtick={-3,-2,...,3},ytick={},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
    axis on top
]

\addplot[samples=501,domain=-sqrt(5):sqrt(5),blue] {2*x^2}
node[anchor=north east,pos=0.25,xshift=-1pt,yshift=-1pt, circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, font=\footnotesize]{$y=ax^{2}$};

\addplot[samples=501,domain=-sqrt(5):sqrt(5),purple] {-x^2}
node[anchor=south west,pos=1, circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, font=\footnotesize]{$y=-\frac{a}{2}x^{2}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation has size font `\footnotesize` (as far as I can see). So I only rearrange your picture ...

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%   \usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={fill=white, inner sep=1pt,font=\footnotesize}
                    ]
\begin{axis}[width=3in,grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-5.5,ymax=10.5,
    restrict y to domain=-5.5:10.5,
    xtick={-3,-2,...,3},ytick={},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    axis on top
            ]
\addplot[samples=51,domain=-sqrt(5):sqrt(5),blue] {2*x^2}
node[anchor=north east,pos=0.25]{$y=ax^{2}$};

\addplot[samples=51,domain=-sqrt(5):sqrt(5),purple] {-x^2}
node[anchor=south west,pos=.9]{$y=-\dfrac{a}{2}x^{2}$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you have special reason to not use recent `pgfplots`? In above MWE I omit `\usepackage{tikz}` since `pgfplots` load it as well.

Comment: The sizes of the `a` and `2` in $y=\frac{a}{2}x^{2}$ are less than the size of the `x`.  I would like to have them all the same size.  (I am not sure it would look nice, but I would like to see how it would look.)

Comment: Indeed, now I see, that in rush i forgot to change `\frac` to `\dfrac`. I correct my answer.